# Username of comitter is not clickable on github website

Tags: git, github

Do you guys know why username of comitter is not clickable in github's "Commit History" ? I set my username by calling

```
git config --global user.name "myname"
```

And it matches my account name but still commits look like they were made by non-github user (no access to profile, no profile picture and etc.)

Comment: Did you also set your `user.email`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GitHub matches contributors by email, so make sure to set `user.email` as well.